# IDLE Settings window won't appear

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-idle

I have installed Python on Windows 10 using newest installer from [here](https://www.python.org/). Everything works fine except one thing, when I want to configure IDLE (Options->Configure IDLE) the Settings windows won't appear and IDLE freezes (not responding). I tried to reinstall Python and even deleted .idlerc directory but the problem persists. Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: This is a hard question.  It is about installation, not about programming, making it is off topic here.  It would be better suited for the python-list mailing list (mail.python.org).  The problem and answer are likely to be fairly specific to your machine.  Anyway, what exact version did you install, exactly how did you install it (what options did you select when installing), and how did you start IDLE.  Does problem occur immediately after start or after doing other things?

Comment: If you start IDLE from Command Prompt with `py -m idlelib`, do you see any message in Command Prompt when IDLE freezes?

Comment: Python 3.9.6 amd64 default installation option plus add Python to PATH and launcher just for me. I start IDLE using start menu. The problem occurs immediately after start. No message appears in Command Prompt when IDLE is frozen. IDLE memory usage keeps growing during frozen state.

Comment: I ran the same binary, mostly default, until Monday, when I upgraded to 3.9.7.  You could try that.  In CommandPrompt, what does `set` show for `HOMEDRIVE`, `HOMEDIR`, and `USERPROFILE`?  Was `.idlerc` created in your user dir?  If so, what does it contain?  If you want to try debugging, in <pythondir>/Lib/idlelib/editor.py, method EditorWindow.config_dialog, add `print('Event', self.top)` before calling the dialog.  Start IDLE in CommandPrompt.  Open Options=>IDLE preferences.  You should see print output in command prompt.

Comment: If that works, try the same thing in configdialog.Configdialog.__init__ and try to find the last statement that executes cleanly.  Then try the same thing in the code for whatever function failed.  Oh, the question about `set` and `.idlerc` is based on thinking that would be the most likely point of failure.  On the other hand, you symptom description does not fit any failure mode that I know of.

Comment: ```HOMEDRIVE=C:```, ```HOMEPATH=\Users\Myname```, ```USERPROFILE=C:\Users\Myname```. Yes, .idlerc is located in my user directory and it contains recent-files.lst file. The last successfully executed statement from configdialog.py is ```self.geometry(f'+{x}+{y}')```. I think the culprit is the next statement ```self.create_widgets()```.

Comment: The last successfully executed statement from ```create_widgets()``` is ```self.highpage = HighPage(note, self.extpage)```. The next statement is ```self.fontpage = FontPage(note, self.highpage)```. Maybe the problem has something to do with font loading.

Comment: Solved! I removed some chess fonts from the system and the settings window pops out normally. Thanks for the guidance.

Comment: Please add a self answer (allowed) with as much detail as possible: font name, source (if you know), and how removed.  Also, which function or line crashed, if you debugged that far.  I have read reports that some characters of some fonts disable some implementations of XWindows on Linux.  This is the first report I have read of anything similar on Windows.  If the problem is only with tk and not Windows graphics system, there might be some way for tkinter/IDLE to recover instead of crash (or hang).  But I need data to experiment.

Answer (score 1):

The problem turned out to be IDLE inability to load some "incompatible" font. In my case it was Phaistos font from [CTAN](https://ctan.org/pkg/phaistos?lang=en) (I was mistaken, the chess fonts are innocent of this problem). In order to reproduce the problem just install Phaistos.otf from the package (right click on the file and click Install). The remedy is quite simple, open Control Panel -> Fonts then locate and select Phaistos Regular font then proceed with clicking Delete button.

UPDATE 1: I have successfully reproduced the issue in another computer unit. I guess this is not specific to my machine.

UPDATE 2: I believe this is the specific statement that is failed to execute cleanly in file configdialog.py

```
for font in fonts:
    self.fontlist.insert(END, font)
```

Comment: Thank you.  I opened https://bugs.python.org/issue45103 to test this further.

Answer (score 0):

Installing 3.9.9 and/or the upcoming 3.10.1 should fix this issue.

The investigation on the [Python tracker](https://bugs.python.org/issue45103) resulted in a tcl/tk bug report, which they claim lead to a fix.  The tcl/tk [8.6.12 release note](https://sourceforge.net/p/tcl/mailman/message/37380142/)  specifically says fixes include " - Windows loading of the Phaistos font."
The 3.9.9 Windows installer includes the tcl/tk upgrade.  3.10.1 will also.