# Python 3.10 IDLE does not respond everytime I hit configure IDLE from options

Tags: python, windows, powershell, cmd, python-idle

I am a Windows 10 user, and had configured the Python 3.10 IDLE to dark mode and had added the Fira Code font to the IDLE a few days back (Through the Options menu). Then the Python IDLE was working fine; without issues.
However, each time after that when I try to go to 'Configure IDLE' from Options Menu, Python IDLE just freezes and then stops responding, until I manually close it. It then asks to run a Windows check and reports the error to Windows. I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling Python; however that did not work.

[Image: Python has stopped responding (happens everytime I click on configure IDLE)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rJQ5x.png)

I am a Windows user and tried running python from cmd using the command: `py -m idlelib` to start IDLE from the command line to try and get an error report, however the same problem happens as mentioned above, and I do not get an error report when I close Python. I tried finding solutions in similar questions, however I did not understand what was going on. I also do not seem to figure out how 'running the Python IDLE' through the command line works, other than running it using the above command. Can someone please assist me on what to do next at this point, that would be of huge help :D

Answer (score 0):

Try uninstalling the font.  The `Doesn't work` part of the `Editor compatibility list` on https://github.com/tonsky/FiraCode includes IDLE.  I suspect that the font is incompatible with tcl/tk.  Your report is similar to
[IDLE Settings window won't appear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68996159/idle-settings-window-wont-appear)
See https://bugs.python.org/issue45103 for so far futile efforts to protect IDLE.

UPDATE: We were not able to reproduce the problem with FireCode.  However, the BPO issue referenced above lead to a tcl/tk bug report that lead to a bugfix, at least for the Phaistos font, that is included in tcl/tk 8.6.12.  This is included in the new Python 3.9.9 Windows installer and will be in the upcoming 3.10.1 installer.  It might fix your issue with FiraCode.

Comment: `py -m idlelib` is the correct way to start IDLE in Windows CommandPrompt or Powershell.  There is no error output because python running IDLE crashed instead of unexpectedly exiting.  On the BPO issue, someone tried and failed to reproduce the issue by installing the font.  So there might be another issue with your system.  I just upgraded to 3.10.0 from the release candidate a few weeks ago.  At the moment, I don't have any other ideas.

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed answer! The problem was solved after deleting Fira Code; though couldn't figure out exactly what was causing the problem was. Thank you for pointing out the Editor Compatibility list on the Github repo!